# Permutation similar graph Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $G$ be an undirected graph and denote $L$ its Laplacian.

If $L$ satisfies $PL = LP$ for all permutation matrices $P$, is then $L$ necessarily the Laplacian of a "noone-to-noone" or the Laplacian of a "all-to-all" graph?

Comment: What do you mean by "noone-to-noone" and "all-to-all" graphs? Do you mean edgeless graphs and complete graphs?

Comment: yes, that is what i meant

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is true. It is a fact that a graph $X$ (with $n$ vertices) is complete or empty if and only if **Aut**$(X)$ contains all transpositions of $\{1, \dots, n\}$. (see e.g. Chapter 1 in Godsil, Royle, *Algebraic graph theory*).

The equation $PL = LP$ gives $D - PDP^{-1} = A - P A P^{-1}$, where $L = D - A$ ($D$ is the degree matrix and $A$ is the adjacency matrix). Inserting a transposition for $P$ directly gives that the graph $X$ is necessarily regular, since $A$ and $P A P^{-1}$ have zero entries on the diagonal. In particular this implies that $D - P D P^{-1} = D - P P^{-1} D = 0$ for *any* permutation, since $D$ is a constant on the diagonal.